# ¿ Unir 2 bases de datos en una?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo un aplicación mysql/php en un computador que sube algunos datos **(facturas/detalles, productos, clientes)** a un **servidor** a través de un web service para poderlo verlo en un dispositivo móvil con una api, a la cual accedo a la **base del servidor/host**, todo función PERFECTO hasta aquí.

El problema es que voy agregar Otro computador con la misma aplicación de facturación, como unificó todo en el servidor/host?

**OJO** Todos los datos son separados, cada uno tiene sus propias facturas, productos y clientes (este debería ser uno solo para ambos)

Pido disculpas de ante mano si no me hago entender.

Comment: En la base del servidor/host agrega un campo `origen` y agregas ahí de que servidor vienen los datos. Luego en el webservice filtras los datos por origen según el cliente que se conecte.

Comment: No puedo hacer eso, por ejemplo el **ID** (clave foránea) de la tabla facturas es única ej: **2567** = 001-002(computador/puesto de facturación )-2567, la tabla productos capaz si fueda hacer eso

Comment: Me toca añadir otra tabla de facturas [facturas002] y así sucesivamente mientras vaya agregando más puntos de facturación?